# Add new class to existing class when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, nav

Hello everyone I try to add a new class 'visible' to existing class 'menu' when the page is ready and all elements are loaded.

This is the code that I use.

```css
.point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.menu ul {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.menu ul li h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.point div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #999;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: grab;
}

.point:hover div {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: grab;
}

nav.menu {
  visibility: hidden;
}

nav.menu.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
  <div class="loading-bar"></div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <li>
      <div class="point point-0">
        <div class="point"></div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h1 href="#">num</h1>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </nav>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pect25L3/

I tryed

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('menu').className = 'visible';
};
```

But nothing happens. Where can be my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: How about classList.add

Comment: It's `window.onload = function() {
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('menu')).forEach(function() { this.classList.add('visible')); }`
};

Comment: `getElementById('menu')` there's no element with id 'menu', you should be using `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: There’s a chance that JSFiddle already puts your code in the equivalent of `window.onload`. The `load` event is only fired a single time. Make sure your code is executed in this context.

Comment: Something does happen.  You get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'className')"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you are trying to use an id selector for a class selector, this is a working code

```
const visibleMenu = () =>{

const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
menu.classList.add('visible')
};
window.onload = visibleMenu()
```

Comment: Should just be `window.onload = visibleMenu` without the `()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is '.menu' is a class in your HTML and you are using 'getElementById' in your JS.

Answer (score 0):

your trying to get class='menu' with getById.  change class to id

```js
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('menu').className = 'visible';
};
```

```css
.point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.menu ul {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgb(66, 66, 66);
}

.menu ul li h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.point div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #999;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: grab;
}

.point:hover div {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: grab;
}

nav.menu {
  visibility: hidden;
}

nav.menu.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
  <div class="loading-bar"></div>
  <nav id="menu">
    <li>
      <div class="point point-0">
        <div class="point"></div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h1 href="#">num</h1>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </nav>
  <script>document.getElementById('menu').className = 'visible';</script>
</body>
```